# Using Fields[0].Value to get XML from FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS query is messed up

Tags: sql, xml, delphi, dbexpress

I have a query that uses FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS to return a SELECT query as a structured XML document. However, when I get the result using a TSQLDataSet by using Fields[0].Value, the result is different from what I see when I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio.

What I see in the result from the TSQLDataSet:

```
੄customerIdфname၄governmentNumberไdebtorAddress1ไdebtorAddress2ไdebtorAddress3ไdebtorAddress4ࡄpostCodeୄcontactNameՄphonë́faxൄcustomerSinceՄtermsلactiveไcurrentBalanceلDebtorခŁ䄁ഃӤ
```

What I see in the result in SSMS:

```
<Debtor>
  <customerId>C0E449E5B2C      </customerId>
  <name>New Customer 2                               </name>
  <governmentNumber>                </governmentNumber>
  <debtorAddress1>Address Line 1                                    </debtorAddress1>
  <debtorAddress4>Address Line 4                  </debtorAddress4>
  <postCode>1234                </postCode>
  <phone>1234567890               </phone>
  <fax>1234567890               </fax>
  <customerSince>2013-06-10T18:16:06.213</customerSince>
  <terms>M   </terms>
  <active>true</active>
  <currentBalance>0.0000</currentBalance>
</Debtor>
```

Is there a particular way it should be executed to get the right result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK this is a `DbExpress` limitation. I know how overcome this, but using ADO (the returned data must be requested using a special parametrized object and a set of ADO streams). However you can use a  workaround converting the XML data to a string in the server side sorrounding the sentence with a select (subquery) or just using a simple CAST statement.

For example if you sentence is like so

```
  SELECT Foo, Bar FROM FooTable FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
```

you can rewrite to

```
 SELECT (SELECT Foo, Bar FROM FooTable FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS)
```

or you can rewrite to (use a CAST VARCHAR or NVARCHAR)

```
SELECT CAST( (SELECT Foo, Bar FROM FooTable FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

and finally

Retrieve the result like this

```
 SQLDataSet1.Fields[0].AsString
```

Comment: Tested a bit and the cast is not necessary. Using a subquery is enough to make it work. `SELECT (SELECT Foo, Bar FROM FooTable FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, TYPE)`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, Thanks I just modified the answer adding your suggestion.